# Seaborn generates a graph in a wrong way

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I've been trying to make a graph out of .csv file.

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('Path/to//Data.csv')

g = sns.relplot(x="time", y="data", kind="line", data=df)
```

data frame looks like:

```
time,data
01-05-98,309
01-06-98,310
01-07-98,311
01-08-98,312
01-09-98,313
01-10-98,314
01-11-98,315
```

The result is generated in the following way:
[image]

Whereas Excel graph is completely different:
[image]

What is the way to fix the graph generated by Python?

Comment: The x axis are probably strings

Comment: That was the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seaborn [lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot) might give you a more sensible plot.

If that doesn't work you might need to convert the `time` column to a datetime column in pandas.

Something like

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m-%d-%y')
```